# how to assign multiple string values to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I am new to python, just start learning :P
I am trying to create a password protected program, but I am stuck in assigning multiple string values to single variable.
can anyone help me solving this problem,
If you guys have better idea for this "login type" program please guide me !

I want to assign all different possible synonyms assign to  one variable so it become easy for user to enter!!!

(my English :P)

```
#Code 1
User_Name = "Allex_Benzz", "allex benzz", "allex_benzz", "Allex Benzz"
User_Input = input("Please Input Your User Name...!\n")
if User_Input == User_Name:
    User_Password = "0011"
    User_Input_Password = input("Please Enter Your Password...!\n")
    if User_Input_Password == User_Password:
        print("Welcome Allex Benzz")
    else:
        print("Your Password Is Incorrect..!")
else:
    print("No Users Found")
```

```
Result Code 1

Please Input Your User Name...!
allex benzz #(User Input)
No Users Found
```

```
#Python login
#Code 2
User_Name = "Allex_Benzz"
User_Name = "allex benzz"
User_Name = "allex_benzz"
User_Name = "Allex Benzz"
User_Input = input("Please Input Your User Name...!\n")
if User_Input == User_Name:
    User_Password = "0011"
    User_Input_Password = input("Please Enter Your Password...!\n")
    if User_Input_Password == User_Password:
        print("Welcome Allex Benzz")
    else:
        print("Your Password Is Incorrect..!")
else:
    print("No Users Found")
```

```
#Result Code 2
#In this case its is only working if I use Allex Benzz because User_Name is setted to Allex Benzz
Please Input Your User Name...!
allex benzz  #User_Input
No Users Found
```

```
#working Result for Code 2
Please Input Your User Name...!
Allex Benzz #User_Input
Please Enter Your Password...!
0011 #User_Password
Welcome Allex Benzz
```

Comment: `"Allex_Benzz", "allex benzz", "allex_benzz", "Allex Benzz"` is a tuple. `if User_Input == User_Name:` won't work, you need to use `in` to check whether the string is in the tuple collection

Comment: In any case, you'd be better converting the user input into the lowest common denominator. `if User_Input.replace(' ', '_').lower() == 'alex_benzz'` and get rid of your collection of alternatives

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks Buddy I used second method and it is working ! But I have to do more research because in my case it is only one user Allex Benzz, what if we have 2 or 3 user so....

BTW Thanks Dear

Edited :

I Got it and all problems are solved

Comment: You can't do that in the general case reliably , though you can always store usernames in lowercase and with spaces converted to underscores. Usernames are very specific for a reason. You also wouldn't store passwords as plaintext. I suspect that question exceeds the limits of what this exercise is supposed to teach you.

Comment: @roganjosh As I said I am new to python so I am reading lessons through w3schools and trying to do some thing then I got an idea to store my all website login passwords in on directory.
So I created a simple program which I can only have to write website name and it show me password of that specific site, well I got an other idea "in between all above process any one who open this program needs a in-build program password with user name,
so that's the whole situation !!!
also google and other password wallets have these password but this above work is for practice (feeling m programmer :P)

Comment: I don't follow what any of that has to do with my comment but I wish you luck with your learning

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
User_Name = "Allex_Benzz", "allex benzz", "allex_benzz", "Allex Benzz"
User_Input = input("Please Input Your User Name...!\n")
if User_Input == User_Name:
    # ...
```

`User_Name` is a tuple of multiple strings, and `User_Input` is a single string.  A single string will never be equal to (`==`) a tuple, but it can be `in` a tuple.  Change the `if` check to:

```
if User_Input in User_Name:
```

and it should work the way you intend.